# A parallel process scenario realization stuck on waiting input

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pipe, fork

I am trying to realize this scenario:

[parallel process scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTUG4.png)

where `ls -l` and `cat /etc/group` processes run parallel, and `tr /a-z/ /A-Z/` takes combined input from them. And then transfers uppercase version of them to either `cat -n` and `grep Z` (they also should run parallel). `cat -n` and `grep Z` should output to stdout.

So in the stdoutput,

`(ls -l ; cat /etc/group) | tr /a-z/ /A-Z/ | cat -n`

`(ls -l ; cat /etc/group) | tr /a-z/ /A-Z/ | grep A`

should be printed.

I've written this program to achieve my goal:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<wait.h>

int main()
{
    int    dummy, i;
    size_t size = 0;
    int    pipe1[2];
    int    pipe2[2];
    int    pipe3[2];
    char* lsargs0[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};
    char* lsargs1[] = {"cat", "/etc/group", NULL};
    char* lsargs2[] = {"tr", "/a-z/", "/A-Z/", NULL};
    char* lsargs3[] = {"cat", "-n", NULL};
    char* lsargs4[] = {"grep", "A", NULL};
    char** am[]     = {lsargs0, lsargs1, lsargs2, lsargs3, lsargs4};
    char buf[4096];

    pipe(pipe1);
    pipe(pipe2);
    pipe(pipe3);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if ( pid == 0 )
        {
            if ( i == 0 || i == 1 ) // ls -l & cat
            {
                // 0 -> stdin, 1 -> pipe write end
                close(pipe2[0]);
                close(pipe2[1]);

                close(pipe3[0]);
                close(pipe3[1]);

                close(pipe1[0]);
                dup2(pipe1[1], 1);
                close(pipe1[1]);

                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            else if ( i == 2 ) //TR AZ AZ
            {
                int extraPipe[2];
                pipe(extraPipe);

                int forkMaster = fork();

                if ( forkMaster != 0 )
                {
                    printf("TR az AZ fork parent\n");
                    //parent
                    close(pipe2[0]);
                    close(pipe2[1]);

                    close(pipe3[0]);
                    close(pipe3[1]);

                    close(pipe1[1]);
                    dup2(pipe1[0], 0);
                    close(pipe1[0]);

                    close(extraPipe[0]);
                    dup2(extraPipe[1], 1);
                    close(extraPipe[1]);

                    //waitpid(forkMaster, &dummy, WNOHANG);
                    //wait(&dummy);

                    execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("TR az AZ child\n");
                    //child
                    read(extraPipe[0], buf, 4095);
                    //printf("%s\n", buf);

                    write(pipe2[1], buf, size);
                    write(pipe3[1], buf, size);
                    close(pipe1[1]);
                    close(pipe1[0]);

                    close(extraPipe[0]);
                    close(extraPipe[1]);

                    close(pipe2[0]);
                    close(pipe2[1]);

                    close(pipe3[0]);
                    close(pipe3[1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if ( i == 3 ) // cat -n
            {
                close(pipe1[0]);
                close(pipe1[1]);

                close(pipe3[0]);
                close(pipe3[1]);

                close(pipe2[1]);
                dup2(pipe2[0], 0);
                close(pipe2[0]);

                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            else if ( i == 4 ) //grep Z
            {
                close(pipe1[0]);
                close(pipe1[1]);

                close(pipe2[0]);
                close(pipe2[1]);

                close(pipe3[1]);
                dup2(pipe3[0], 0);
                close(pipe3[0]);

                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
            //DON'T FORGET TO CLOSE PIPES ON PARENT
        else if ( i == 4 )
        {
            close(pipe1[0]);
            close(pipe1[1]);

            close(pipe2[0]);
            close(pipe2[1]);

            close(pipe3[0]);
            close(pipe3[1]);
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        wait(&dummy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the program stucks on `read(extraPipe[0], buf, 4096);` line. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: `small.c:97:29: error: 'n' may be uninitialized...` Did you compile the code you put as an example? You need to test it before posting it.

Comment: I did compile with gcc successfully. But for you, I moved that line which caused error in your compiler, can you please try again?

Comment: What is the compile command you use? I recommend at least `-Wall` you would have be warned your varriable was not initialized (which leads to undefined behaviour).

Comment: I did use `-Wall` flag and it compiles without any warning now. You may look at the code.

Comment: Trying to understand now, what's that for loop with j variable supposed to do? You're closing some file descriptors twice!

Comment: It was supposed to redirect the output of `tr /a-z/ /A-Z/` to `pipe2` and `pipe3`, but as you say I used it in incorrect way. I've changed it now, may you please look at it now again?

Comment: Please do not update your code in your question anymore, this leads to outdated comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two processes `i == 2` are still waiting for each other. I moved backward some `close()` and it seems to work properly. Also need a `loop` for the duplicating process and an `exit(0);` rather than a `break;`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main()
{
    int    dummy, i;
    size_t size = 0;
    int    pipe1[2];
    int    pipe2[2];
    int    pipe3[2];
    char* lsargs0[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};
    char* lsargs1[] = {"cat", "/etc/group", NULL};
    char* lsargs2[] = {"tr", "/a-z/", "/A-Z/", NULL};
    char* lsargs3[] = {"cat", "-n", NULL};
    char* lsargs4[] = {"grep", "A", NULL};
    char** am[]     = {lsargs0, lsargs1, lsargs2, lsargs3, lsargs4};
    char buf[4096];

    pipe(pipe1);
    pipe(pipe2);
    pipe(pipe3);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        /*if (pid > 0)
            printf("pid %d = %ld\n", i, (long) pid);*/

        if ( pid == 0 )
        {
            if ( i == 0 || i == 1 ) // ls -l & cat
            {
                // 0 -> stdin, 1 -> pipe write end
                close(pipe2[0]);
                close(pipe2[1]);

                close(pipe3[0]);
                close(pipe3[1]);

                close(pipe1[0]);
                dup2(pipe1[1], 1);
                close(pipe1[1]);

                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            else if ( i == 2 ) //TR AZ AZ
            {
                int extraPipe[2];
                pipe(extraPipe);

                int forkMaster = fork();

                if ( forkMaster != 0 )
                {
                    printf("TR az AZ fork parent\n");
                    //parent
                    close(pipe2[0]);
                    close(pipe2[1]);

                    close(pipe3[0]);
                    close(pipe3[1]);

                    close(pipe1[1]);
                    dup2(pipe1[0], 0);
                    close(pipe1[0]);

                    close(extraPipe[0]);
                    dup2(extraPipe[1], 1);
                    close(extraPipe[1]);

                    //waitpid(forkMaster, &dummy, WNOHANG);
                    //wait(&dummy);

                    execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("TR az AZ child\n");
                    //child
                    close(pipe1[1]);
                    close(pipe1[0]);
                    close(pipe2[0]);
                    close(pipe3[0]);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Line %d\n", __LINE__);
                    close(extraPipe[1]);
                    do
                    {
                        size = read(extraPipe[0], buf, 4095);
                        if (size > 0)
                        {
                            write(pipe2[1], buf, size);
                            write(pipe3[1], buf, size);
                        }
                    } while (size > 0);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Line %d\n", __LINE__);
                    //printf("%s\n", buf);


                    close(extraPipe[0]);
                    close(pipe2[1]);
                    close(pipe3[1]);

                    exit(0);

                }
            }
            else if ( i == 3 ) // cat -n
            {
                close(pipe1[0]);
                close(pipe1[1]);

                close(pipe3[0]);
                close(pipe3[1]);

                close(pipe2[1]);
                dup2(pipe2[0], 0);
                close(pipe2[0]);

                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            else if ( i == 4 ) //grep A
            {
                close(pipe1[0]);
                close(pipe1[1]);

                close(pipe2[0]);
                close(pipe2[1]);

                close(pipe3[1]);
                dup2(pipe3[0], 0);
                close(pipe3[0]);

                execvp(am[i][0], am[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
            //DON'T FORGET TO CLOSE PIPES ON PARENT
        else if ( i == 4 )
        {
            close(pipe1[0]);
            close(pipe1[1]);

            close(pipe2[0]);
            close(pipe2[1]);

            close(pipe3[0]);
            close(pipe3[1]);
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        wait(&dummy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```